# Why does Access sometimes include source table name in query default column aliases?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Every now and then I have a query which **Access insists on automatically prefixing *every* column with the source table/query name**. Adding an alias to the source does not help--that alias is just prefixed to each returned column name.  It sometimes happens when there is only one source so there is no chance of conflicting column names to start with, but I have also observed it with joins on multiple tables.

When creating or editing a simple query in Design View, one can select columns from a source table (or query) without having to specify an explicit alias.  As one would expect, the returned columns assume the names of the source columns (with no additional qualifier--usually **no table names prefix the column names**).  This is even true when joined tables have columns with the same name, assuming that only one of the possibly-conflicting columns is selected in the query.

Example where both [Products] and [Details] have an [ID] column:

```
SELECT Products.ID, Products.ItemName, Details.Description
FROM Products INNER JOIN Details ON Products.ID = Details.ForeignID
```

Results in these columns

```
| ID | ItemName | Description |
```

If default column names conflict, then Access automatically prefixes the resultant column names with the source table, *but only for the particular columns that conflict with each other*:

```
SELECT Products.ID, Products.ItemName, Details.ID, Details.Description
FROM Products INNER JOIN Details ON Products.ID = Details.ForeignID
```

Results in these columns

```
| Products.ID | ItemName | Details.ID | Description |
```

(Interestingly, periods are not allowed in explicit column aliases, yet the automatically-prefixed names with periods work fine even in subsequent queries.)

If the SQL is edited and saved without allowing the Design View to muck it up again, the prefixes can usually be eliminated from the result by removing the source reference from the SELECT clause, like `SELECT Details.Description` -> `SELECT Description`.  (An explicit alias also works like `SELECT Details.Description As Description`, but that is really beyond my question since I am wondering about why Access seems to randomly add the source prefix *automatically*.)

Here is my most recent query that exhibits this annoying default behavior.  I can't see any reserved names or other features of the query that should cause this... and as I already mentioned, I can delete all `Detail.` occurrences and it works great with simple column names:

```
SELECT Detail.[Board Order], Detail.[Sales Rep], Detail.[Sales Team], Detail.[Sales Year],
  Detail.[Team Name], Detail.[Date of Service], Detail.[Service Year],
  Detail.[Service Month], Detail.[Service Week], Detail.[Service Codes],
  Detail.Account, Detail.[Last Name], Detail.[First Name],
  Detail.AsOfDate
FROM [Rep Completed IS Detail As Of] AS Detail
WHERE (((Detail.[Service Year])=Year([Detail].[AsOfDate])) 
  AND ((Detail.[Service Week])=DatePart("ww",[Detail].[AsOfDate])))
```

Results in these columns

```
| Detail.Board Order | Detail.Sales Rep | Detail.Sales Team | ...
```

I can't figure out a pattern for this behavior.  Does anyone know when / why this happens?

Comment: is the question about the prefix or the field enclosed by  "[ ]"?

Comment: It's about the prefix.

Comment: i think it's a normal behaviour if you drag and drop the fields to the design view and i find it helpful. if you are not happy with it then write your own queries but then if you join multiple tables with the same column names make sure you alias it properly. the behaviour is also in SQL Server

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Thanks and I regret that my question was so long... but I was worried about misunderstanding if I did not include details and examples. If you re-read the second paragraph, you will see that I mentioned the _usual_ behavior in Access -- columns names are usually **not** prefixed with the source (table or query) names except when there are obvious name conflicts.  It is only rarely that I observe the behavior that I explained where ALL columns are prefixed.  I also mentioned that I am aware that I can alias each column, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: in terms of the last result where it's dotted, try using single word column names ie. Board_Order

Comment: If having spaces in the names is _part of the reason_ (?) for the behavior, I would consider removing all spaces.  However, I have used spaces in names of many, many tables and columns and usually don't have this issue.  I just did another test using other tables with spaces in names and this did not cause the behavior.

Comment: I have never seen this behavior, except when columns from different tables have the same name (conflicting names). I don't use spaces in column names, but still this is very odd. Can you share a sample database only with the table and query?

Comment: @Andre I'll consider it, but I'd have to scrub the database and delete most queries and tables... and then confirm it still happens.  It also uses linked tables, so I'd either have to convert to local tables and see if it still happens, or I'd have to send both back and front end.  Either way, it would take some work and I won't be able to do it immediately.  Thanks for being willing to look at though.